# Lazy loading in oj-tree-view in 4.x

Tags: oracle-jet

I was using Oracle Jet 3.2 and the oj-tree supported lazy rendering of child elements. I am upgrading to OJet 4.1 and I am not able to figure out how to support this(lazy rendering) in the new implementation of tree,  i.e. oj-tree-view. There aren't any relevant examples in the cookbook too. The oj-tree-view code too doesn't help much

I guess the old oj-tree(from 3.2) would still work as they claim to be backward compatible but I would like to upgrade the code to 4.1 level.

Comment: Could you show your 3.2 code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the way 4.x ojTree works is you'll need to attach a datasource while defining the tree. Something like `<oj-tree-view id="treeview" data ="treeDataSource"....` .  `treeDataSource` here can be an instance of `oj.CollectionTreeDataSource`  which provides a callback param, `childCollectionCallback`. This callback is always invoked when you try to expand a tree node. We can have our logic to fetch the data from server here.